# NSFetchedResultsController Not Updating Upon Return from Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I have a Core Data entity called GarmentTypes displayed in a UITableViewController subclass which implements NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, and has an NSFetchedResultsController as a property.  A modal seque presents a new view controller where a new GarmentType can be added.  Upon dismissal of the modal view controller, the underlying UITableViewController does not update.  I know that the GarmentType entity is saved in the database because it is shown if I back out to the previous view controller and then re-seque.  You can see a video demonstrating here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DahKMgVxDho

I have created a generic class called CoreDataTableViewController which implements NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and has an NSFetchedResultsController property:

```
@interface CoreDataTableViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

I subclass CoreDataTableViewController as GarmentTypesCDTVC to display the GarmentTypes.  It has one property, the NSManagedObjectContext:

```
@interface GarmentTypesCDTVC : CoreDataTableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
```

The context is retrieved in its viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [DressyHelper openDocumentUsingBlock:^(UIManagedDocument *document){
        self.context = document.managedObjectContext;
    }];
}
```

The fetch request is created when the setter for the context:

```
- (void)setContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    _context = context;
    if (context) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"GarmentType"];
        request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
        request.predicate       = nil; // All GarmentTypes
        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    } else {
        self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    }
}
```

DressyHelper hands out the UIManagedDocument:

```
// Open or create a UIManagedDocument.
+ (void)openDocumentUsingBlock:(completion_block_t)completionBlock;
{
    // Get documents directory and path.
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url        = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DressyDocument"];

    // Create the document and open if a match exists on file.
    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (!success) NSLog (@"Couldn't open document at %@", url);
            else completionBlock(document);
        }];
    } else {

        // No match exists, so save the document to file.
        [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (!success) NSLog(@"Couldn't create document at %@", url);
            else completionBlock(document);
        }];
    }
}
```

I've read similar questions and tried implementing without success, so I apologize if this turns out to need a similar solution, but I've been racking my brain on this for some time.  For instance, placing a [self.tableView reloadData]; in the GarmenttypesCDTV's viewWillAppear: has no effect.

TIA

Update: here is the .m for CoreDataTableViewController:

```
//
//  CoreDataTableViewController.m
//  Dressy
//
//  Created by Michael Mangold on 9/6/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Michael Mangold. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CoreDataTableViewController.h"

@interface CoreDataTableViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL beganUpdates;
@end

@implementation CoreDataTableViewController

#pragma mark - Properties

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext;
@synthesize debug = _debug;
@synthesize beganUpdates = _beganUpdates;

#pragma mark - Fetching

- (void)performFetch
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController) {
        if (self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching %@ with predicate: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName, self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate);
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching all %@ (i.e., no predicate)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName);
        }
        NSError *error;
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
    } else {
        if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] no NSFetchedResultsController (yet?)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)setFetchedResultsController:(NSFetchedResultsController *)newfrc
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *oldfrc = _fetchedResultsController;
    if (newfrc != oldfrc) {
        _fetchedResultsController = newfrc;
        newfrc.delegate = self;
        if ((!self.title || [self.title isEqualToString:oldfrc.fetchRequest.entity.name]) && (!self.navigationController || !self.navigationItem.title)) {
            self.title = newfrc.fetchRequest.entity.name;
        }
        if (newfrc) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), oldfrc ? @"updated" : @"set");
            [self performFetch];
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] reset to nil", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
}

#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        self.beganUpdates = YES;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if (self.beganUpdates) [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges
{
    _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = NO;
}

- (void)setSuspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext:(BOOL)suspend
{
    if (suspend) {
        _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = YES;
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges) withObject:0 afterDelay:0];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Side note: You might want to put the Done button in the top right and the Cancel button in the top left.

Comment: Put breakpoints to see what NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods aren' being called.

Comment: Why are you opening the UIManagedDocument in viewWillAppear ? Seems odd to do this because this may be called multiple times and I would expect you to only do this once when the app starts and then use the context in each module where you access core data objects.  You're opening the document then going to another view to create an new object then when you go back to the previous view you end up opening the document again??  Are you closing the document somewhere in these transitions ?

Comment: No, I'm not closing the document.  Opening the document in viewDidLoad made no difference to the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by passing the context to the table view controller which adds the new GarmentType.  I had been calling my helper class' openDocumentUsingBlock: again to get the context.  I assumed that I'd be safe using a new instance of the context because it is a property of the same UIManagedDocument.  Guess I was wrong.  Thanks to those that responded.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the `NSFetchedResultsController`, you didn't actually set its delegate.

//After this

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

//Add this

```
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

You also need to implement some `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods. [Apple has docs on how to do this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for responding, @Kevin, but setting the delegate did not fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, Kevin.  Thanks for responding again.  Which delegate method would you like to see?

Comment: Updated answer with a link to Apple's example

Comment: Hi, Kevin.  I've added the .m for CoreDataTableViewController which implements the delegate methods.